# passing a functor into a dll for reproting progress

Tags: c++, dll, functor

I have a dll which is I am writing it as c++ on visual studio 2013.

As part of this dll, there is a function which takes a long time to finish and I need to inform the caller progress ( as a percent and also a string).

My idea is that this function accept a function from caller and call it when there is any progress changes.

My questions:

1- is it make any problem if I pass a functor into a class which is reside inside a DLL? Where can I find a simple sample?

2- is there any better way to do this, If I don't want to use any third party library (such as boost)?

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg I thinks yes as I am using VS 2013.

Comment: you could try passing function. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function It's in the c++11 standard so no third party library would be needed.

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg Thanks, I am wondering if I can pass it to a dll? Please note that I am not using share run time and hence the std::function on the calling side may be different from the implementation on the dll side and I am not sure how that would effect this behaviour.

Comment: I see... So basically the library can be compiled on the different architecture than the user? Maybe you could compile it with x86 compatibility? Not sure though if this can be a case here...

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better design choices. But there is no problem with passing a function pointer or a functor object to a dll function.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please give a sample code? what about std::function? is it safe to pass it into a dll?

Comment: Yes, it is sa to pass a std::function to your dll. For an example see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: For a progress listener, what exactly are the "better design choices" you are referring to?
I guess in C-style APIs it is pretty common to pass function pointers or structs for purposes like this.
Are you referring to C++ 11 features like std::function?